# Form is not working inside model in laravel 4.2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

when I inspected my code I found that my form tag is not available inside the modal-body.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Change Profile Pic</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- <div> -->
                <form role="form" method="POST" id="profile_pic_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ URL('/profile_pic_change_userdashboard') }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_profile_id" value="{{$user_details->id}}">
                    <input type="file" name="profile_img_pic">
                    <input type="submit" name="profile_img_change" id="profile_img_change" class="btn">
                <form>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

I want that inside my model the form tag is visible and working, which is currently not the case.

Comment: Please include your relevant code in the question so we can see what the problem might be. :)

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi rohit is it possible to share error what you faced while compiling following code.
and please check form tag is not closed proper. so do that first and check and also share error which you faced